# Connecting to Active Directory remotely

Tags: active-directory, remote-access, remote

This post seems to be half programming and half administration, so I'm not sure where it belongs. Neither SO nor SU seem exactly right. Feel free to redirect as appropriate.

Old situation:

Existing PHP website, inside the domain, connecting to Active Directory for authentication and identity when users log in to the app.

New situation:

Moving the website to a VM on Azure. Not moving AD. Need to connect to AD remotely.
They don't want to move to Azure AD just for this.

I've been told that the previous developer found a plugin that helped with making this connection, and it worked fine when they tested it. So they decided to go ahead with this project, just before they had a falling out.

Based on that info, I assumed this would be a straightforward project, but I've not found anything similar and received no notes about said plugin.

It doesn't appear that they used a VPN, but I might have to fall back to that if I can't get it to work otherwise.

Note that this is not Remote Desktop or remote administration of AD, but remote authentication of users.

UPDATE:
Authenication currently looks like this, where Bind returns a boolean:

```
    // Authenticate against LDAP
    $linkLdapConnection = ldap_connect($this->objConfiguration->sDomainName);
    if (!$linkLdapConnection) {
        $this->aReadOnlyVars['sSecurityError'] = "Domain connection failure.";
        return false;
    }

    $bLdapBind = @ldap_bind($linkLdapConnection, $sUserLogin . "@" . $this->objConfiguration->sDomainName, $sUserPassword);
```

Comment: What are you asking about exactly -- how to implement authentication in your software, or how to make it go through the corporate firewalls?

Comment: Look into Azure Active Directory Services. AADS is designed to support domain members implemented on azure as though they were using the on-prem. you will need domain synch to AADS.  regular old Azure Active Directory won't do this, since it doesn't do machine domain related stuff like kreberos.  Note that Express Route and some types of VPN don't support UDP traffic so LDAP connections are not possible. I'm facing this at my work, and we just wrote a proxy service that will proxy back domain info about users using a restful service over TCP protocols.

Comment: @user1686, the topic of hybrid cloud/on-prem connectivity is a tricky one with azure (not nearly so simple as firewall configuration), and most of the recommended options won't pass LDAP traffic due to protocol limitations on the connecting circuit. As a result, apps that relied on the domain for services will not be able to reach a domain controller when moved to azure. the IAAS solution is to implement a domain controller in azure and synch with onprem, but if you are restricted to PAAS solutions, it gets complicated fast.

Comment: @FrankThomas: That sounds like very specific to Azure networking and could be avoided by using another sort of VPN? (Such as the built-in IPsec tunnel support in Windows Server.) But in this case, the app is written in PHP, so it is very unlikely to be calling the Windows AD functions that want to do the UDP-based DC pings or all of the other AD-specific protocols. If it only uses the generic LDAP extension that comes with PHP, it'll be fine with just TCP access.

Comment: @user1686 Perhaps I was thrown off track by the "knowledge" that I needed a plugin to enable this.  Looks to me like LDAP can connect natively to any IP. Do I just need to open the firewall then?

Comment: @BWhite: One more thing, does the VM run Windows Server, or is the web app hosted on Linux/BSD? (And if the VM runs Windows, is the whole server domain-joined?)

Comment: @user1686 Windows,  yes, Domain,  no. This is the only thing on the server, so I suppose it could be joined, but that feels like it opens whole other cans of worms.

Answer (score 0):

While domain-joined hosts use loads of protocols for communicating with Active Directory (all of them TCP/IP based, fortunately), at its core you have two standard ones: Kerberos for secure authentication and LDAP for user directory access.

---

If your only goal is to *check passwords* (as in the code exammple you've posted), you don't actually need to be using any AD-specific software – the 'ldap' module that's part of PHP will be enough.

However, when dealing with generic LDAP, in the initial line of code –

```
$linkLdapConnection = ldap_connect($this->objConfiguration->sDomainName);
```

– it likely will not be enough to specify just the domain name; instead you'll need to specify the full URL of a specific server, such as `ldaps://ad.example.com` or `ldaps://dc01.ad.example.com`.

LDAP works over TCP ports 389 or 636, as far as firewall configuration goes. (The Windows AD-specific functions may also use UDP port 389 for "DC pings", but a generic LDAP client does not do this.)

As you're sending plain passwords to the server, you *definitely* want to use LDAP with TLS – either by specifying an `ldaps://` URL, or by calling `ldap_start_tls()`. The former will use TCP port 636 and is more foolproof, while the latter will use port 389 instead.

(This also means that the domain controller must have [a valid TLS certificate](https://sectigo.com/resource-library/install-certificates-microsoft-active-directory-ldap-2008) installed. Not all domains have one, as Windows itself prefers using Kerberos protection and doesn't need TLS.)